# installing and building multiple packages from source with pip

Tags: python, pip, installation

I want to create a Python package. To make this work, the user needs to install multiple python packages. I also need the user to install a package that is currently only supported for installing straight from the source (i.e. `pip install -e .`). How do I create my own source package, which depends on another source package in a clean way? In my opinion, it would be best if the user can just run `python setup.py` once; which installs my package and all the requirements in `requirements.txt` as well as the other package straight from the source.

I added a `setup.py` file with the following content:

```
setuptools.setup(
    dependency_links=["git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch-dp.git#egg=pytorch-dp"],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
)
```

When I run the setup file I get:

```
Moving pytorch_dp-0.1-py3.6.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Adding pytorch-dp 0.1 to easy-install.pth file
```

but then if I try to import the package `torchdp`:

`import torchdp`

I get the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchdp'`

I'm using a Google Colab Notebook for GPU support.*

Comment: `-e` and "straight from source" are not the same in my understanding. For me, "straight from source" might just be something like `pip install git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git`. Could you clarify where the other dependencies are located? do they come from a git repo, do you package them with your application ...?

Comment: Thanks that worked smooth! I didn't know. I just had to use #egg=eggname at the end.

Comment: @FlyingTeller Please check my new question. I updated it because it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had to restart google colab, and then it worked. Yikes.